# replace variable with resampling

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, for-loop

How could i replicate this line below as a forloop? This line worked:

```
data= data.resample('W').last()

data
date        result
2010-01-10  0.53
2010-01-17  0.55
```

To convert to a forloop, I tried this. This raises no error, but doesn't modify the data at all:

```
listxx = [(data, "data")]
for (x, y) in listxx:
    x = x.resample('W').last()
```

Comment: You can provide a sample of your data as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/6692898

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(listxx):
    listxx[i] = x.resample('W').last()
```

Comment: Would this work too for the second line:   ```listxx[i] = x.set_index('date').dropna(how='all').resample('W').last()```

Comment: Anything you want to do to list[i] in terms of modifying it... just don't remove it. The loop is going through consecutive items and removing one item will cause unwanted results